# Best approach for grid layout

Tags: html, css, grid

Ok so this question is more of a "best approach type of deal" or I'm doing it wrong.

I've been using a grid system for several projects at this point and I pretty alternate between appraoches how I construct the general layout. Both wasy seem to  work fine, I was just wondering which one makes more sense logically.

So lets says my application has a sidebar on the left and a content area on the right.

I have been doing it one or the other way

A.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="grid_4 sidebar"></div>
 <div class"grid_8 content"></div>
</div>
```

B.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="grid_12 wrap">
  <div class="grid_4 sidebar alpha"></div>
  <div class"grid_8 content omega"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

My questions is which is a better approach and why.

Comment: Considering that B isnt valid HTML I would pick A. Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: That was a typo sorry.

Comment: The question is relevant to me for many of the grid systems out there.

Comment: If they function the exact same, I would say the one with less markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A** makes the most sense for simple pages.

In essence, **B** `<div class="grid_12 wrap"></div>` is just a second container.  If there's something above or below your content that is still within your container `<div>`, this might make sense.  It allows you to "contain" the grid area but still keep everything inside the container.

If this is your entire grid, you're better off going with the simpler markup.  **A** will be easier to track down issues later when your code is longer or more complex.  I can't count how many times I've lost track of my nested `<div></div>` tags, especially when working in notepad/text editor or when my markup isn't clear in an authoring editor.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with **A**, at least that is how JQuery Mobile handles grids.

[JQuery Mobile Grids](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/grids/)

Comment: Similarily bootstrap itself uses the same approach as seen here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/